# how to use eclipse remote debug web html pages?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web

I have remote connected web service using the function of "remote java application" but I can only debug the java code, now I want to debug the html pages or js code.how could I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKTg1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to debug the HTML and Javascript of your application

1:Download Firebug from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=search and add it to Firefox browser

2: Restart the firefox browser and open your application in it.

3: Press **F12** and apply breakpoints in the script files